# OS X Server continuous integration error with adding server to the team

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, osx-server

I'm encountering an error when trying OS X server (Maverick) for continuous integration.

When adding developer teams I'm having [this error](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5278)

I don't know where to look inside system.log it's flooded with messages.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

(Is it OK if my OS X server is installed from the app store with an Apple ID that's not in the Apple developer program?)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by updating to the latest version of OS X Server. What version of Server are you running?

I was running an older version of OS X Server (2.2... something) and running into the same problem. As soon as I updated OS X Server via the App Store to 3.1 or whatever the latest is, I was able to add a server to several teams with no errors.